# Access Database exceeds 5000 items and doesn't function in SharePoint because of that

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010, web-access

I have a table in Microsoft Access that contains much more then 5000 items. In addition, I created a MS access form which I published in SharePoint. In this form, the users have to select some options and at the end a filtered table will be returned.

On the server it works with no issues. But when I try to generate the filtered table on SharePoint, the message "Failed to retrieve list data" appears. It's because the table contains more then 5000 items. When I reduce the amount of items, it works.

Ironically with the use of my filters, the user should never get a result with more then 1500 items. But because the database has in total more than 5000, it doesn't allow to filter the table to begin with.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Delete the data from table, generate it on SP, then add rows

Answer (score 0):

If your user group is employing terminal services / remote desktop servers - one could deploy a split Access database without relying on SharePoint.  This is possibly of no help whatsoever...…

SharePoint for sharing files, docs, etc - I understand.  But a multi user database application is kind of a different animal....